# Расположение элементов по разным краям

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким свойством или группой свойств реализуется подобное?

[image: ,]

Известно, что это `ul` и `li` внутри блока `div`. То есть каждый новый `li` чередуется.

Если можно, оставьте ссылку, где можно прочитать про подобные свойства.

Comment: подобное что? круг что ли? выкладывайте, пожалуйста, код, описывайте проблему более детально, так намного будет проще понять вопрос и помочь

Comment: `text-align: left` и `right` соответственно

Comment: нашел информацию..то с помощью селекторов `nth-child(2n)` (вроде) сделано , когда каждый второй элемент списка принимает определенные стили